# Solving a PDE ( wave equation )

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

$$u_{tt}- \Delta u= e^{t}, 0<x<2\pi, 0<y<1, t>0$$
$$u_x(0,y,t)=u_x(2\pi,y,t)=0, 0<x<2\pi, t>0$$
$$u_y(x,0,t)=u_y(x,1,t)=0, 0<x<2\pi, t>0$$
$$u(x,y,0)=0, 0<x<2\pi, 0<y<1$$
$$u_t(x,y,0)= 1+\cos(x), 0<x<2\pi, 0<y<1$$
Can anyone please help me? I am learning PDE and I have no idea how to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kind of wave equation you are dealing with, is non-homogeneous. We first try to solve the homogeneous wave equation $u_{tt}=\Delta u={\partial^2u\over \partial^2 x}+{\partial^2u\over \partial^2 y}$ given initial condition using [Separation of Variables Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables). We first define $u(x,y,t)=f_1(x)f_2(y)g(t)$. Then by substituting we obtain$$u_{tt}=f_1(x)f_2(y)g''(t)\\\Delta u={\partial^2u\over \partial^2 x}+{\partial^2u\over \partial^2 y}=f_1''(x)f_2(y)g(t)+f_1(x)f_2''(y)g(t)\\\implies\\f_1(x)f_2(y)g''(t)=f_1''(x)f_2(y)g(t)+f_1(x)f_2''(y)g(t)\\\implies \\{g''(t)\over g(t)}={f_1''(x)\over f_1(x)}+{f_2''(y)\over f_2(y)}$$The above equation states that a summation of three functions of **pure** $x,y,t$ is zero. This is possible **only if they are all constants**, i.e.$${g''(t)\over g(t)}=k\\{f_1''(x)\over f_1(x)}=k_1\\{f_2''(y)\over f_2(y)}=k_2\\k=k_1+k_2$$Now, let's turn back to our own equation. As the non-homogeneous term on RHS (i.e. $e^t$) is a function of $t$, not $x,y$ we neglect it for now (there is a very simple way to add it later). The most important thing now is to determine the signs of constants $k,k_1,k_2$, which has a dramatic effect on out answer, for example if $k$ is positive, the answer of the first equation takes an **exponential form** and with $k<0$ we attain to a **sinusoidal shape**. The case $k=0$ has no matter of significance, since it leads to linear unbounded answer $at+b$ for constants $a,b$. Furthermore, since the constraints are bounded along $x$ and $y$, we argue that **our final answer should have a sinusoidal form along $x$ and $y$** leading to $k_1,k_2<0$. Define $$k_1\triangleq-\lambda_1^2\\k_2\triangleq-\lambda_2^2$$therefore $$k=-\lambda_1^2-\lambda_2^2=-\lambda^2$$and our **partial** answers for $f_1,f_2,g$ become:$$f_1(x)=a_1\cos \lambda_1 x+a_2\sin \lambda_1 x\\f_2(y)=b_1\cos \lambda_2 y+b_2\sin \lambda_2 y\\g(t)=c_1\cos \lambda t+c_2\sin \lambda t$$therefore$$u_0(x,y,t;a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2,c_1,c_2)=\\(a_1\cos \lambda_1 x+a_2\sin \lambda_1 x)\cdot(b_1\cos \lambda_2 y+b_2\sin \lambda_2 y)\cdot(c_1\cos \lambda t+c_2\sin \lambda t)$$but we are not finished yet! Since the equation is linear, any combination of the **partial** answers is an answer itself (that's why we called the answers found as *partial* beforehand), finally$$\hat u(x,y,t)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(a_{1n}\cos \lambda_{1n} x+a_{2n}\sin \lambda_{1n} x)\cdot(b_{1n}\cos \lambda_{1n} y+b_{2n}\sin \lambda_{2n} y)\cdot(c_{1n}\cos \lambda_n t+c_{2n}\sin \lambda_n t)$$But why changing $\lambda$ to $\lambda_n$? To include higher harmonics of the partial answers!

> **Final kicking off**
>
> We solved the equation when it was homogeneous. To include $e^t$ in
>   our answer, note that if $u(x,y,t)$ is an answer to the homogeneous
>   equation, then $u(x,y,t)+e^t+at+b$ is an answer to the main,
>   non-homogeneous wave equation. Therefore
>   $$u(x,y,t)=\\e^t+C_1t+C_2+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_{1n}\cos \lambda_{1n}
>  x+a_{2n}\sin \lambda_{1n} x)\cdot(b_{1n}\cos \lambda_{2n} y+b_{2n}\sin
>  \lambda_{2n} y)\cdot(c_{1n}\cos \lambda_n t+c_{2n}\sin \lambda_n t)$$

**Applying initial condition**

Note that$$u_x(x,y,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-a_{1n}\lambda_{1n}\sin \lambda_{1n}
 x+a_{2n}\lambda_{1n}\cos \lambda_{1n} x)\cdot(b_{1n}\cos \lambda_{1n} y+b_{2n}\sin
 \lambda_{2n} y)\cdot(c_{1n}\cos \lambda_n t+c_{2n}\sin \lambda_n t)$$ and $$u_y(x,y,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_{1n}\cos \lambda_{1n}
 x+a_{2n}\sin \lambda_{1n} x)\cdot(-b_{1n}\lambda_{2n}\sin \lambda_{2n} y+b_{2n}\lambda_{2n}\cos
 \lambda_{2n} y)\cdot(c_{1n}\cos \lambda_n t+c_{2n}\sin \lambda_n t)$$Now by throwing $x=0$ and $x=2\pi$ in $u_x(x,y,t)$ we obtain$$x=0\implies a_{2n}=0\\x=2\pi\implies \lambda_{1n}={n\over 2}$$similarly from $u_y(x,y,t)$ we obtain$$y=0\implies b_{2n}=0\\y=1\implies \lambda_{2n}={n\pi}$$also $u(x,y,0)=0$ therefore$$c_{1n}=0\\C_2=-1$$and finally$$u(x,y,t)=e^t-1+C_2t+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}d_n\cos{\lambda_{x,n}}x\cos{\lambda_{y,n}}y\sin{\lambda_{n}}t$$Now from our last condition we have$$u_t(x,y,0)=1+C_2+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\lambda_{n}}d_n\cos{\lambda_{x,n}}x\cos{\lambda_{y,n}}y=1+\cos x$$which yields to $$C_2=0\\\lambda_n=\lambda_{x,n}=1\\d_n=1\\\lambda_{y,n}=0$$

> ***Final answer***$$u(x,y,t)=e^t-1+\cos x\sin t$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just one question. Whould you please explain more how you deduced that $k_1$ and $k_2$ are negative.